# NodeJS require file from absolute path

Tags: node.js

I need to import some js files from the user's file system, I can't seem to do it using the absolute path of that file, I get the `Cannot find module` error

```
// /home/paul/Desktop/File.js
 module.exports = {
   data: "random string"
  }

// Where I actually import it
  const files = await fsPromises.readdir(desktopPath);
  files.forEach((file) => {
    if (/.*\.js$/.test(file)) {
      const myImport = require(path.join(desktopPath, file));
      console.log(myImport);
    }
  });
```

The error

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/paul/Desktop/File.js'
    at webpackEmptyContext (webpack:///./src_sync?:2:10)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/background.js?:218:65)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/background.js?:216:9)
    at async electron/js2c/browser_init.js:197:563 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

When I click on the file path it opens my `File.js`

Comment: Can you provide some code to make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @theusaf I've added an example

Comment: Can you also add the code where you are trying to import the module?